# Displaying bitmap image in imageview by simple adapter

Tags: android, listview, imageview, simpleadapter

I am getting image from an url. I am using imageview in listview. I want to add the list of bitmap images into the each row of the list item. I used SimpleAdapter but the imageview shows blank.My code is below !!

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>>();

    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
     get = bundle.getString("name");

     try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.propertyhookup.com/mobile/propertylist.php");
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipcode", get.trim()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

  //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if(result.length()<= 7){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No properties for this zipcode or check your zipcode ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //text.setText("No properties for this zipcode or check your zipcode");
    }
    else{
    try{

     jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.111/propertyhookup.com/mobile/propertylist.php");

    try{

        JSONArray  earthquakes = jArray.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){                      
            map = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
            //HashMap<String, Drawable> map1 = new HashMap<String, Drawable>();

            JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);



            if(e.getString("property_type").contains("1")) {
                proptype ="Single Family Home";
            }else if(e.getString("property_type").contains("2")) {
                proptype="Condo";
            }else if(e.getString("property_type").contains("3")) {
                proptype="Townhouse";
            }
            if(e.getString("estimated_price").contains("0")) {
                estimate = "Not Enough Market Value";
                //estimat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.estimat);
                //estimat.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 23));
            }else {
                estimate = "$"+e.getString("estimated_price");
            }

            photo = e.getString("photo1");

            drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(photo);

            //text.setImageDrawable(d);

            try
            {
                    aURL = new URL(photo);
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e1)
            {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            URLConnection conn = null;
            try
            {
                    conn = aURL.openConnection();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try
            {
                    conn.connect();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStream is = null;
            try
            {
                    is = conn.getInputStream();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedInputStream bis = new
    BufferedInputStream(is,8*1024);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

            map.put(photos, bm);
            mylist.add(map);


        }       
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main4, 
                   new String[] { "percent","propertyid",  "cityname", "statecode", "propertytype", "footage", "bathroom", "bedroom", "price", "estimated", "photos" }, 
                   new int[] { R.id.percent, R.id.property_id,  R.id.city_name, R.id.state_code, R.id.prop_type, R.id.foot, R.id.bath, R.id.bed, R.id.list, R.id.estimat, R.id.image});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think is because you are downloading the image from web and you need to do these in ASYNC see painless thrething download image and after that refresh just the imageviews.

Comment: Plz give me an example how to exucute my above code to add images through simple adapter. Or else how to display image into my imageview. I am new to android plz help me out!!

Answer (score 11):

Basically the simple adapter automatically bind some ressource id or URI to the imageview of your row layout.
But it don't support Bitmap.

That's a problem, because everyone who had to manage bitmap know that we often have to reduce the size of the picture to prevent outOfMemory exceptions.
But if you want to add images into a listView, you cannot reduce the image's size if you only provide URI. So here is the solution :

I have modified the simpleAdapter to be able to handle bitmap.
Add this class into your project, and use it instead of simpleAdapter.
Then instead of passing an URI or a ressourceId for an image, pass a Bitmap !

Hereunder is the code :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class ExtendedSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
    List<? extends Map<String, ?>> map; // if fails to compile, replace with List<HashMap<String, Object>> map
    String[] from;
    int layout;
    int[] to;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ExtendedSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, // if fails to compile, do the same replacement as above on this line
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) { 
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        layout = resource;
        map = data;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.context = context;
    }


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return this.createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, layout);
}

private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent, int resource) {
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }

    this.bindView(position, v);

    return v;
}


private void bindView(int position, View view) {
    final Map dataSet = map.get(position);
    if (dataSet == null) {
        return;
    }

    final ViewBinder binder = super.getViewBinder();
    final int count = to.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {
            final Object data = dataSet.get(from[i]);
            String text = data == null ? "" : data.toString();
            if (text == null) {
                text = "";
            }

            boolean bound = false;
            if (binder != null) {
                bound = binder.setViewValue(v, data, text);
            }

            if (!bound) {
                if (v instanceof Checkable) {
                    if (data instanceof Boolean) {
                        ((Checkable) v).setChecked((Boolean) data);
                    } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                        // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                        // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                        setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() +
                                " should be bound to a Boolean, not a " +
                                (data == null ? "<unknown type>" : data.getClass()));
                    }
                } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                    // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                    setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                    if (data instanceof Integer) {
                        setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Integer) data);                            
                    } else if (data instanceof Bitmap){
                        setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Bitmap)data);
                    } else {
                        setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                            " view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



private void setViewImage(ImageView v, Bitmap bmp){
    v.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}



}
```

This class behave exactly like the original class (SimpleAdapter)

Comment: I tried using your code in autocompletetextview to display an image with text but I couldnot make it work. Could you provide an example or is it even possible to use this in autocompletetextview?

Comment: Thanks for the contributon. A tip: your constructor doesn't match SimpleAdapter's. This way we can't just change SimpleAdapter to ExtendedSimpleAdapter in an existing code. You can improve that. (for instance: for me, I needed to change the constructor from List<HashMap> to List<Map> so it could work)

Comment: Hello Leonardo. You are right and welcome.
I will change in my answer the code List<HashMap<String, Object>
with the code List<? extends Map<String, ?>> as I just seen in the Android L SimpleAdapter source.

subash, sorry I did not see your question earlier, tell me if I can be of any help.

Comment: Since it's been one year that I left the Android/Java world, I am not sure the modifications I made will compile. It should, but if anyone can confirm me that this new revision of my code is working, I would appreciate.

Comment: how to use this class with listview?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to create a class that extends BaseAdapter and then instanciate an async task for every image (on post execute set the bitmap to the correpondent imageView). Here's a simple function to download an image from web:

```
private Bitmap loadImageFromNetwork(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()));
}
```

Comment: My problem is not with downloading image. In my above code i added the bitmap image got from url into the simpleadapter to display in listview with imageview. But when am running the code the image view is empty. What can i do for that

Comment: Is R.id.image an ImageView? Try this: `code` SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main4, 
                   new String[] { "percent","propertyid",  "cityname", "statecode", "propertytype", "footage", "bathroom", "bedroom", "price", "estimated", "photos" }, 
                   new int[] { R.id.percent, R.id.property_id,  R.id.city_name, R.id.state_code, R.id.prop_type, R.id.foot, R.id.bath, R.id.bed, R.id.list, R.id.estimat});
    setListAdapter(adapter);`code`

The first N views in "to" list are given the values of the first N columns in the "from" parameter.

Comment: Ya right.. R.id.image is an ImageView only.But how do your code work for me? U didn't declare the id for the ImageView in SimpleAdapter.

Comment: As you can see here: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]%29) you just need to declare the textViews. But why don't you create a class that extends BaseAdapter? [link](http://bit.ly/m1bJuX) But instead of using an array with the image IDs you can call an async task and do `i.setImageBitmap(image)` on post execute.