# add Image Bitmap to Simple Adapter Android

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, imageview, simpleadapter

I had some problem here. Let assume I already convert `String` to `Bitmap` perfectly but when I want to display to `ListView` using `SimpleAdapter` , its show nothing in `ImageView`.

Here, my snap Code:

I already define the variable:

```
imageProduct = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageId);
```

This is to Get and Convert Image from JSON:

```
JSONArray productDetails = new JSONArray(jsonStr2);
for(int j=0 ;j<productDetails.length();j++){
    HashMap<String, Object> productData = new HashMap<String,Object>();     
    JSONObject q = productDetails.getJSONObject(j);
    String productName = q.getString("Name");
    String productPrice = q.getString("Price");
    String productImage = q.getString("Image");
    String encodeImage = productImage.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","").replace("data:image/png;base64,","");
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodeImage,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap base64Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString,0,decodedString.length);
    productData.put("productName",productName);
    productData.put("productPrice",productPrice);
    productData.put("base64Bitmap",base64Bitmap);
    orderDetailList.add(productData);
}
```

And I want to show the image with this adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
                    OrderDetailActivity.this, orderDetailList,
                    R.layout.list_item_product, new String[]{"productName","productPrice","base64Bitmap"},
                    new int[]{R.id.productName,R.id.productPrice,R.id.imageId}
            );
    lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
}
```

"Name", and "Price" is showed perfectly , but Image isn't . What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved, according to this : [Displaying bitmap image in imageview by simple adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327465/displaying-bitmap-image-in-imageview-by-simple-adapter)

Just Create That Class and use it to simple adapter that you have.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy just follow this code...

```
    adapter1.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder(){

                @Override
                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                                            String textRepresentation) {
                    if( (view instanceof ImageView) & (data instanceof Bitmap) ) {
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data;
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;

                }

            });

    lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Hope you enjoy.